# Remove the Whitespace

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

Direction:
Display the list without white space in the beginning of every row in SSRS by using expressen code.

Requested result:

```
a
------------------
aaa
aaa ss
bb - bb-
ss - -dd
ddd ddd
dd dd dd - dd
```

Obstacle:
How should I enable to remove the white space in order to achieve the requested result.

Information:
The data is taken from a table (dimension table) in SSAS.
THe data will be used inside of a textbox.

Current situation:

```
a
------------------
   aaa
 aaa ss
   bb - bb-
  ss - -dd
          ddd ddd
   dd dd dd - dd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LTrim("string")
```

That should be all you need. Where to apply it I'm not sure without more info

EDIT:

If the data is being put into a textbox, just use it as an expression for the box.